# PowerPoint in Delphi: fill table with text

Tags: vba, delphi, powerpoint

I'm writing an add-in to PowerPoint in Dephi XE3, which would insert a table and fill it with some text. I am almost done with it, but I can't fill a table with text.

This is my code:

```
insp:=CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
insp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank);
MSTable:=insp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1);
MSTable.Shapes.AddTable(5, 5, 100, 0);
MSTable.Table.Cell(2,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text:='Text';
```

When I'm trying to fill a table, I'm getting this error

> Method 'Table' not supported by automation object

Also tried this:

```
MSTable.AddTable(5, 5, 100, 0).Cell(2,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text:='Text';
MSTable.Table.Item(1).Cell(2,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text:='Text';
```

On MSDN found how to write this code in VBA, but doesn't help. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please change "an error" to "this error" followed by the real error message

Comment: If 'addtable' is a method of 'MSTable.Shapes', then maybe you need to write MSTable.Shapes.Table.item(1).cell (2,2)......:= 'text';

Comment: @No'am Newman, unfortunately same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273476%28v=office.14%29.aspx) thats the way you should create and access the `PowerPoint`-table

```
var
  LApp, LSlide, LTable : Variant;
begin
  LApp := CreateOleObject( 'PowerPoint.Application' );
  LSlide := LApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add( 1, ppLayoutBlank );
  LTable := LSlide.Shapes.AddTable( 5, 5, 100, 0 ).Table;

  LTable.Cell( 2, 2 ).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text := 'Text';
```

Comment: As you can see I just followed the VBA example ;o)